# JPype and JayDeBeAPI: AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'isBeanAccessor'

Tags: python, jdbc, jpype, jaydebeapi

I have built JPype (JPype1-0.5.5.4) along with JayDeBeAPI 0.1.4 in my attempt to connect to a database via JDBC. This is on RHEL. I can successfully connect using the driver,

```
TrgtCnn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver',
                          ['jdbc:as400://<mask>','<mask>','<mask>'],
                          '/app/as/lib/jdbc/jt400.jar')
```

but I get this traceback in JPype when I execute SQL:

```
TrgtCrs = TrgtCnn.cursor()
TrgtCrs.execute("SELECT * FROM WA6U999S")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5d46ea8c382d> in <module>()
----> 1 TrgtCrs.execute("SELECT * FROM WA6U999S")

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/dbapi2.pyc in execute(self, operation, parameters)
    356             parameters = ()
    357         self._close_last()
--> 358         self._prep = self._connection.jconn.prepareStatement(operation)
    359         self._set_stmt_parms(self._prep, parameters)
    360         is_rs = self._prep.execute()

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JPype1-0.5.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_jclass.pyc in _getClassFor(javaClass)
     66         return _CLASSES[name]
     67 
---> 68     pyJavaClass = _JavaClass(javaClass)
     69     _CLASSES[name] = pyJavaClass
     70     return pyJavaClass

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JPype1-0.5.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_jclass.pyc in __new__(mcs, jc)
    123         elif not jc.isInterface():
    124             bjc = jc.getBaseClass(jc)
--> 125             bases.append(_getClassFor(bjc))
    126 
    127         if _JAVATHROWABLE is not None and jc.isSubclass("java.lang.Throwable"):

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JPype1-0.5.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_jclass.pyc in _getClassFor(javaClass)
     66         return _CLASSES[name]
     67 
---> 68     pyJavaClass = _JavaClass(javaClass)
     69     _CLASSES[name] = pyJavaClass
     70     return pyJavaClass

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JPype1-0.5.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_jclass.pyc in __new__(mcs, jc)
    166         for i in _CUSTOMIZERS:
    167             if i.canCustomize(name, jc):
--> 168                 i.customize(name, jc, bases, members)
    169 
    170         # remove multiple bases that would cause a MRO problem

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JPype1-0.5.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_properties.pyc in customize(self, class_name, jc, bases, members)
     68 
     69         def customize(self, class_name, jc, bases, members) :
---> 70                 accessor_pairs = _extract_accessor_pairs(members)
     71                 for attr_name, (getter, setter) in accessor_pairs.items():
     72                         if attr_name in members:

/app/as/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/JPype1-0.5.5.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_properties.pyc in _extract_accessor_pairs(members)
     46                         if _is_java_method(members[property_name]):
     47                                 continue
---> 48                 if access == 'get' and member.isBeanAccessor():
     49                         try:
     50                                 pair = accessor_pairs[property_name]

AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'isBeanAccessor'
```

I have no idea where to start on this and can't seem to find anything mentioning anything close to this issue.

Comment: This has been fixed: https://github.com/originell/jpype/commit/60b0130b4bf056fd46556607b84bd2b795530e4f BTW: have you tried https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi It allows you a more pythonic access using jdbc+jpype and hides the java stuff from your code...

Comment: Oops, I didn't see you are already using JayDeBeApi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be [a bug in JPype](https://github.com/originell/jpype/issues/63).

I don't have access to an AS/400 database, but I do have an Oracle XE database lying around and I was able to use that to reproduce the problem.  The Python code I used was as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver', ['jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE', 'user', 'password'])
print conn
```

I found what I believe to be a fix for the problem,  which I have posted to the JPype issue above.  This fix was to edit the function `_extract_accessor_pairs` in `jpype/_properties.py`, find the following code and replace the `or` with an `and`:

```
    for name, member in members.items():
            if not (len(name) > _PROPERTY_ACCESSOR_PREFIX_LEN \
                          or _is_java_method(member)):
                    continue
            # rest of loop omitted...
```

After making this change, the error I was getting went away.  You're welcome to try this fix and see if it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks @Luke, I've used your suggestion 1:1 to fix the bug

Comment: @bastian: no problem, glad to have helped.  (For those that don't know, bastian is one of the JPype project maintainers.)